# Insert post Blogger API failing with Python

Tags: python, google-api, blogger, google-api-python-client

This code now works.

I'm having an issue inserting a new blog post on to google's Blogger site via python2.7 calling an API.
I have all the oauth2client modules from google to handle the authentication.
I have permission to use the Blogger V3 api - this is activated on the google developer console.
I have run simple api requests with the same credentials.dat that have worked:

this worked (full code not included)

```
service = build('blogger','v3', http=http)
try:
    request = service.blogs().get(blogId="6814573853229626501")
    response = request.execute()
    print response
```

The google api discovery service leads me to believe this is what the code should look like to insert a post
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/blogger/v3/blogger.posts.insert

```
service = build('blogger','v3', http=http)

try:
    body = {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "id": "6814573853229626501",
        "title": "posted via python",
        "content":"<div>hello world test</div>"
        }

    request = service.posts().insert(blogId="6814573853229626501",body=body)

    response = request.execute()
    print response
```

I'm sure it's the body=body part that I'm messing up?  Any clues?

here is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blogger.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "blogger.py", line 93, in main
    response = request.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_api_python_client-1.0c2-py2.7.egg/apiclient/http.py", line 654, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, self.uri)
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/6814573853229626501/posts?alt=json returned "Invalid Value">
```

If you're interested I'm experimenting with posting charts from my google fusion tables generated by eBay data that i'm interested in at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the "data": object wrapper around your data, the client library will add that if the server needs it. This documentation shows the form of the object to use in the insert call:

https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/blogger/v3/python/latest/blogger_v3.posts.html#insert

Comment: Fantastic!
Worked great.  Edited the above code to show the correct solution.

Comment: Can you please share the entire code including the authentication code? I am having problems with this too. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can post on any blogger somehow

```
__author__ = 'spandey2405@gmail.com (Saurabh Pandey)'

import sys
from oauth2client import client
from googleapiclient import sample_tools

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'blogger', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger')

  try:

      users = service.users()

      # Retrieve this user's profile information
      thisuser = users.get(userId='self').execute()
      print('This user\'s display name is: %s' % thisuser['displayName'])

      blogs = service.blogs()

      # Retrieve the list of Blogs this user has write privileges on
      thisusersblogs = blogs.listByUser(userId='self').execute()
      for blog in thisusersblogs['items']:
        print('The blog named \'%s\' is at: %s' % (blog['name'], blog['url']))

      posts = service.posts()
      body = {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "id": "6701167141462934671",
        "title": "posted via python",
        "content":"<div>hello world test</div>"
        }
      insert = posts.insert(blogId='6701167141462934671', body=body)
      posts_doc = insert.execute()
      print posts_doc


  except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run'
      'the application to re-authorize')
```